# No entiendo que estoy haciendo mal. ¿Por qué la función .then() no se está ejecutando?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

Estoy intentando leer un valor de la base de datos de firebase pero estoy confrontando un problema y no entiendo claramente donde está el error.

Este es el código.

```
function checkPublishButton(){
  $( "#publish_button" ).click(function(){
  //Check if a user is logged in.
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    //Declare firebase data-base
    var database = firebase.database();      
    //Get user's total event created counter
    return database.ref("users/" + user.uid ).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      console.log("This is not executing");
      return snapshot.val().total_event_created;
    }).then(function(counter) {
      //Increase the total_event_counter by one
      console.log("This is also not executing");
      var counter = counter +1;
      database.ref('users/'+user_id+'/total_event_created').set(counter);  
      //Get input from form
      var title = $("#title").val();
      var date = $("#date").val();
      var hour = $("#hour").val();
      var place = $("#place").val();
      var brief_description = $("#brief_description").val();
      var detailed_description = $("#detailed_description").val();
      var contact_email = $("#contact_email").val();
      var contact_phone_number = $("#contact_phone_number").val();
      var imageUrl = $("#imageUrl").val(); 
      //Post event into firebase database
      database.ref('events/' + user_id + '/' +  counter).set({
        title: title,
        date: date,
        hour: hour,
        place: place,
        brief_description: brief_description,
        detailed_description: detailed_description,
        contact_email: contact_email,
        contact_phone_number: contact_phone_number,
        imageUrl: imageUrl
      });
    });              
  });
});
}
```

Para que tengan una idea, los códigos desde ambos console.log() no se está ejecutando.

Comment: Si el codigo lo has copiado tal cual de lo que tienes, fijate que te faltaban las comillas de cierre en los `console.log`

Comment: Debió haber sido un error, tienen las comillas de cierre. Los console.log() los añadí aquí para mostrarles.

Comment: El then es del auth el que no funciona ?

Answer (score 0):

no conozco tanto de firebase, pero al leer el código me da la impresión de que estas mezclando events con functions y observers. Tu codigo dice:

```
Cuando se ejecute checkPublishButton
  escuchar click event en "#publish_button"
    cuando se clickee publish_button:
      escuchar si se loguea el usuario de firebase
        cuando se loguee
           console.log("This is not executing");
```

Es decir, para ver los cambios, tendrías que ejecutar checkPublishButton(), hacerle click al boton, y luego loguearte como usuario en firebase.

Me parece que lo ideal seria agregar el click event SIN necesidad de que este dentro de una funcion, una vez que se clickee el boton, comprobar los datos en firebase SI es que el usuario esta autenticado:

```
<script>
  // cuando el doc se termine de cargar
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    // escuchar onclick event en publish button:
    $( "#publish_button" ).click(function(){
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        if (user != null) {
            var database = firebase.database();
            //Get user's total event created counter
            return database.ref("users/" + user.uid ).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
              console.log("This is not executing");
              return snapshot.val().total_event_created;
            }).then(function(counter) {
                // ...
            });
        } else {
          console.log("Usuario no autenticado");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Acabo de implementar tu recomendación, pero sigue pasando lo mismo :/